# Writing a part of a dictionary into a text file

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I need to create a text file containing an account number between two fixed sets of data.

The output I need is the following:

```
someData|acc1|someMoreData
```

The data I need to populate is in a file called data.txt. It looks like this:

```
name,acc1,acc2
```

I store this data as a list of dictionaries in the code, as I loop through it in another process.

The code I tried is as follows:

```
import csv, os

with open('data.txt') as csvfile:
reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile,
                        fieldnames=['name', 'acc1', 'acc2'])
clientData = list(reader)


file = open('textfile.txt', 'w')
file.write('someData|')
file.write(clientData['acc1'])
file.write('|someMoreData')
file.close()
```

When I try the code above, I get a TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str.

How can I access the acc1 part and have it written into the text file?

Comment: It's not quite clear what you want to achieve. Do the input and output files both have multiple lines?

Comment: The input sometimes does and sometimes doesn't. The output will have multiple lines.

Comment: So `someData` and `someMoreData` will be the same in every line? Something like `someData|1|someMoreData;someData|2|someMoreData;someData|3|someMoreData`?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 1):

You specifically converted your input to a list.  This means that you have to index it with an integer.  Also, your input is in CSV format, not dictionary format.

I won't give you the entire solution, but here's how to debug it and learn a little:

```
with open('data.txt') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile,
                            fieldnames=['name', 'acc1', 'acc2'])
    print "READER:", reader
    clientData = list(reader)
    print "LIST DATA:", clientData
```

Now that you know how your code sees these things, look up how to use a DictReader to ingest data in the format you want.

Finally, look into looping statements.  I assume that you have multiple lines in this format, and you want to write a separate line of output for each.  You have only one line's worth of output coming from your current code, so you'll need something vaguely like

```
 for input_record in reader:
     file.write("someData|" + input_record[index] + "|someMoreData"
```

I leave that **index** for you to figure out; it should be either "acc1" (dictionary format) or **1** (list format).

Answer (score 0):

You're casting `clientData` to a list, it's not a dict. Try accessing `clientData` by integer indices.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are experiencing is that you are actually **NOT** using dictionaries at all, in fact, you are using Python's lists. There is a significant difference between these two data structures. Here is an example:

```
list = [1,2,3,4]
dict = {'one':1, 'two':2, 'three':3, 'four': 4}
```

In this example the following can happen:

```
list[1]     #Valid
list['one'] #Invalid
dict[1]     #Invalid (Because of a key error)
dict['one'] #Valid
```

This all happens because of the differences between lists and dictionaries. In a list each **value** has a memory location that can be **indexed** via the square brackets. In a dictionary each **value** has a **key** that it can be accessed by. By value and key I mean the following:

```
dict = {'one':1, 'two':2, 'three':3, 'four': 4}
          ^            ^
         key         value
```

Hope this helped and happy coding!